# how to get best current address from List<Address> for same latitude and longitude?

Tags: android, gps, location

I am building an android application which detects user's current location.I am able to get the best location.But I am not getting the best address when I am doing this:

```
List<Address> addresses = gc.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
```

When I am retrieving more than 1 address for the same latitude and longitude then one of the address is correct.

```
List<Address> addresses = gc.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 3);
```

My question is how to compare the list of addresses received to get the best current address.Any suggestion will highly be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

getFromLocation returns result or results depends on maxResults paramater. If you set it as 1 you will get 1 result, if you set it to 3 you will get 3 results (if there are).

But you can not know which is the best, but you can assume 1. is the best

> Parameters
>
> latitude  the latitude a point for the search
>
> longitude the longitude a point for the search
>
> maxResults    **max number of addresses to return. Smaller numbers (1 to 5)
>   are recommended**

Comment: I agree with you..maxresult gives number of addresses.My problem is its not necessary that my 1st address is correct..thats why I want to ask if there is any other way or logic to compare those list of addresses obtained from **List<Address> addresses = gc.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 3);**

Comment: What kind of comparing do you need ? For best location or same address or not ? If you are looking for best location you can not as i said in my answer.